# PHP is confused when adding and concatenating

Tags: php, sum, concatenation, parentheses

I have the following code:

```
<?php

    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;

    echo "sum: " .  $a + $b;
    echo "sum: " . ($a + $b);

?>
```

When I execute my code I get:

```
2
sum: 3
```

Why does it fail to print the string `"sum:"` in the first echo? It seems to be fine when the addition is enclosed in parentheses.

Is this weird behaviour anywhere documented?

Comment: If your question has been answered, you can accept the answer. This marks the question as resolved.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both operators the addition `+` operator and the concatenation `.` operator have the same [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), but since they are left associative they get evaluated like the following:

```
echo (("sum:" . $a) + $b);
echo ("sum:" . ($a + $b));
```

So your first line does the concatenation first and ends up with:

```
"sum: 1" + 2
```

(Now since this is a numeric context your [string gets converted to an integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) and thus you end up with `0 + 2`, which then gives you the result `2`.)

Comment: [Technically they have equal precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) so it's all down to associativity.

Answer (score 8):

If you look at the page listing [PHP operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), you'll see that the concatenation operator `.` and the addition operator `+` have equal precedence, with left associativity.  This means that the operations are done left to right, exactly as the code shows.  Let's look at that:

```
$output = "sum: " . $a;
echo $output, "\n";
$output = $output + $b;
echo $output, "\n";
```

This gives the following output:

```
sum: 1
2
```

The concatenation works, but you then try to add the string `sum: 1` to the number `2`. [Strings that don't start with a number evaluate to `0`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion), so this is equivalent to `0 + 2`, which results in `2`.

The solution, as you suggest in your question, is to enclose the addition operations in brackets, so they are executed together, and then the result of those operations is concatenated.

```
echo "sum: " . ($a + $b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use the language construct [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) you can use a comma to separate the addition from the concatenation:

```
echo "sum: " , $a + $b;
```

Works as expected.