# My PHP SQL query is throwing errors, even though it works in the SQL console

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a function for my forum that will increment my user's "Posts" attribute by 1.  For whatever reason, the following PHP does not work.

```
function postCountIncrease($username) {
    //get the connection variable
    global $con;
    //change to the users database (this function works correctly)
    sqlconnect_users();
    //get current post number (this is also working)
    $getCurrentPosts = "SELECT Posts\n"
    . "FROM users\n"
    . "WHERE Username='".$username."'";
    $query1 = mysqli_query($con, $getCurrentPosts) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $currentPosts = mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
    //here is the problematic post.  Assume that $username is a valid value, and that I've already done mysqli_real_escape_string() on it
    $incrementPostsQuery = "UPDATE users.users SET Posts=". $currentPosts[0]+1 ." WHERE Username='". $username ."'";
    $query2 = mysqli_query($con, $incrementPostsQuery) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    //return the result
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
    return $result;
}
```

I honestly don't see what I'm doing wrong, because the SQL works fine.  If I use `UPDATE users.users SET Posts=1 WHERE Username='Lampitosgames'` in the console, it works with no errors.  Help is much appriciated.  Also, here is the error it is throwing at me:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 WHERE Username='Lampitosgames''
```

Comment: See [Php confused when adding and concatenating](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10841238).

Answer (score 1):

You can not concatenate that way `"toto ".$var+1`, you have to surround with brackets `"toto ".($var+1)`

In your case, this is declaration of var `$incrementPostsQuery` which fails

Answer (score 0):

Look at your errors, your syntax is off

```
$getCurrentPosts = "SELECT Posts 
                    FROM users 
                    WHERE Username='$username'";
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the building of your query.

```
$incrementPostsQuery = "UPDATE users.users SET Posts=". $currentPosts[0]+1 ." WHERE Username='". $username ."'";
```

I'll suggest you some tips to create query like this:

- "update table set field = value";     // you can write the value directly
- "update table set field = ". $value;  // easy
- "update table set field = ". ($a+$b); // ...
- "update table set field = {$value}";  // you can add a variable with curly braces
- "update table set field = {$va[3]}";  // more compless way
- "update table set field = {$a->b}";   // an object field