# PHP output string with variable?

Tags: php

I don't understand why it output `-2yyy` !

How can I output `xxx8yyy` ?

```
$ten = 10;
$two = 2;

echo "xxx".$ten - $two."yyy"; //-2yyy
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "xxx".($ten - $two)."yyy";
```

Try this.

Comment: He could probably benefit from an explanation.

Comment: See this answer for very clear explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/10841238/1743833

Answer (score 0):

Just add brackets:

```
<?php
$ten = 10;
$two = 2;

echo "xxx".($ten - $two)."yyy"; // xxx8yyy
```