# displaying the value of a variable in a string with php

Tags: php

I am unsure of why the desired output is not displaying correctly.
I am trying to get it to display like this:

> 15.55 + 2.94 = 18.49

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
    $operand1 = 15.55;
    $operand2 = 2.94;
    echo("$operand1 + $operand2 = ".$operand1+$operand2);
?>
```

I have also tried:

```
<?php
    $operand1 = 15.55;
    $operand2 = 2.94;
    echo($operand1." + ".$operand2." = ".$operand1+$operand2);
?>
```

Both end up displaying only 18.49.
I have searched on google and looked on [Here](http://www.dummies.com/programming/php/how-to-display-php-variable-values/), Which states that it should be enclosed in double brackets to get the value of the variable.
And also on [w3Schools - example 3](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp) Which shows the second attempt i have put, Yet it only seems to display the answer and not the string itself.

I have also looked on the suggested answers on SO for the question, yet i have not come across one directly related to this question for PHP, So apologies if this is a duplicate but i have tried looking.

Comment: You tried different things and did some research. That's great! Now for next time look at the relevant code and look at all the things that are involved and read the corresponding manual page(s) carefully (For your case: `echo`, `+`, `.`, variables). Even though in this specific example it might still have been hard to spot the "error".

Comment: @Rizier123, Thank you for linking me that question, I could not find it, after reading a bit more, i found that i should have encased the variables like so: echo($operand1 . " + " . $operand2 . " = " . ($operand1 + $operand2));.

Comment: The [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10841124) is linked right under the banner "This question already has an answer here:" at the top of your question?! The second answer on the duplicate might be a bit better than the first one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10841238