# How can i use + in php mail message body for add two number

Tags: php

```
$message_body="<tr><td>Rs. ".$getOrdPro['price']+$getOrdPro['price2']."</td></tr>";
```

When i add two price so destroy my mailer structure

Comment: Use parentheses. This has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP is confused when adding and concatenating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841124/php-is-confused-when-adding-and-concatenating)

Answer (score 1):

Thats a wierd one, still not sure why it messes up but this works

```
$message_body = "<tr><td>Rs. $getOrdPro[price]+$getOrdPro[price2]</td></tr>";
```

Comment: This appears to be why: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php#41950